# Woocommerce custom calculation function

Tags: functions, customization, woocommerce-offtopic

i need some help to add one function in my functions.php.

I think is simple but can't figure how.

Values from woocommerce post id

```
$first_value = $price; //our $sale_price
$second_value = $wcj_multicurrency_base_price_exchange_rate_2;
$final_value = $first_value * $second_value; // number with 2 decimal
```

and save the `$final_value`

because i need them for output in another way...

Thank you

Comment: what all have you tried?

Comment: I'm need help, not tried anything wiet.

Comment: You should read [How to ask](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), you must do some research before asking, for this particular question I can give you a clue, you can save price multiplier in options table and use `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data` to do the calculation on add to cart, if you are looking for complete multi currency website, you can go with any plugin.

Comment: it seems like you are already using a plugin, [here's the documentation for same](https://booster.io/features/woocommerce-multicurrency-currency-switcher/)

Comment: Yes. But need these value for output in a xml feed... Thanks

Comment: how are you generating XML feed?

Comment: Many questions,from, woo feeds by webappick plugin.

Comment: no one can help you without knowing what you want to do, since you are getting annoyed, I'll also not tell you the solution!

Comment: The link [link]https://webappick.com/

Comment: Sorry, but only need one final value, multiply by two values. Is to complicated for you?

Comment: If I had a solution to this question. I would not be here to put it on. But if I can, I'll put the solution here.

Comment: It's easy, but your question was very unclear and still some points are not clear to me because I haven't used any these 2 plugins and I don't prefer asking you anymore question for clarification.